# How to use message properties in TagLib

Tags: grails, internationalization, taglib

As I try to use a message properties in taglib of my grails application it is empty.

```
<g:set var="pos" value="${message(code:"rating.positive.title")}" />
<foo:bar someNew="bla" positiveTitle="${pos}" bean="${item}" />
```

results in log of the attrs of taglib (def bar)

```
someNew=bla
positiveTitle=
bean=item
```

Any idea why this won't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Quotation marks `" vs '`.

I'd try:

```
<g:set var="pos" value="${message(code:'rating.positive.title')}" />
```

instead of:

```
<g:set var="pos" value="${message(code:"rating.positive.title")}" />
```